# SQL Reporting Services - Can I Sum on field that contains expression?

Tags: sql, service, reporting

If I have a field in my SQL 2008 report that is generated via expression (meaning not directly from a dataset) should I be able to `SUM` it?  Can I reference the field in a subsequent expression somehow - like by referencing the box name?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't completely clear...  but I'll take a stab at it.

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(GET_RANDOM_NUMBER()) as randomSum
FROM Table_That_Has_Infinite_Rows
WHERE rowId BETWEEN 3 AND 8
```

This will sum 6 numbers (because the range of a `BETWEEN` statement is inclusive on both ends).
You won't be able to reference the field alias 'immediately' in the `WHERE` clause -

```
SELECT SUM(GET_RANDOM_NUMBER()) as randomSum
FROM Table_With_One_Row
WHERE randomSum > 5  -- throws error, field 'does not exist'
```

However, it will be available in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, and also if you wrap the query in something else (CTE, inline table, etx);

```
SELECT SUM(GET_RANDOM_NUMBER()) as randomSum
FROM Table_With_Thousand_Rows
GROUP BY randomSum  -- although this won't have any apparent effect here
```